# How to check whether a function is real analytic or not

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f \in C[0,1]$, consider the function $F(\eta) = \int_{[0,1]}e^{-ix\eta}f(x)dx$. The problem is to show that it is a real analytic function and find its radius of convergence for its expansion centered at $0$. I know the definition of a real analytic function, but I am confused in general how to show that a function is real analytic. I think I want to probably examine $e^{-ix\eta}$ first. Expand it at zero, I would get $e^{-ix\eta} = (-ix)^n\sum \eta ^n$, and the radius of convergence is the whole $\mathbb R$ if $|x| < 1$. So this function is analytic on the whole real line? How do I actually prove that the formula on its right is its expansion?

Answer (score 1):

Verify that it is allowed to say
$$F'(\eta)=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\eta}\int_0^1e^{ix\eta}f(x)\,\mathrm dx
=\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\eta}e^{ix\eta}f(x)\,\mathrm dx
=\int_0^1ix e^{ix\eta}f(x)\,\mathrm dx
 $$
and this is again of the given form.

Observe that $F$ and all its derivatives are bounded by $\|f\|_\infty$ and plug this fact into the Taylor error term.

Comment: I know how to take the derivative of $F$ using dominate convergence theorem. However, my main issue is to show that the expansion actually is equal to $F$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not only real analytic, but complex analytic in the whole plane.

I like [Morera's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem).

For each fixed $x$, the function $F_x(\eta) := e^{-ix\eta}f(x)$ is an analytic function of $\eta$.  Therefore, for any closed contour $\gamma$, we have
$$
\int_\gamma F_x(\eta)\;d \eta = 0
$$
Now use Fubini's theorem as follows:
$$
\int_\gamma F(\eta)\;d\eta = \int_\gamma\left(\int_{[0,1]}F_x(\eta)\;dx\right)d\eta
=
\int_{[0,1]}\left(\int_\gamma F_x(\eta)\;d\eta\right) dx
= \int_{[0,1]} 0\;dx = 0 .
$$
This holds for all closed contours $\gamma$, so $F$ is analytic by Morera's Theorem.

Comment: So I guess a plausible way to do this is to show that it can be extended to a complex analytic function, thus real analytic on the whole real line?